# How to link students with form questions in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I have the entities like this

1. Student
2. Feedback_categories
3. Feedback_questions
4. Answers

THe form is like below

Techical Questions (category)

- Q1. Which class you are in  -- Text Box Input

  Q2. Which languages do you know --- Text Input

General Questions (category)

- Q1. Which area you are in  -- Text Box Input

  Q2. Which pllaces do you know --- Text Input

My problem is

1. Whether to link Student with either `questions` or `category` or `answers`. 
   These questions are fixed for each student but all students will have different answers
2. DO i need to execute the function so that when i create a student then those question id and gets entered in student table or i don't need it
3. At start there will be no answers stored for student. so do i need to first create empty answers in answers table so that when student opens the form on web site then i can bind the form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the way that I would do it, I hope this helps. I can address some of your problems more in depth (as a comment), I really don't understand the questions fully. Notice that every table name is plural and every column directly related is singular.

```
Students

|id | name      | 
|---|-----------|
|0  | Thomas    |
|1  | Fred      |
|2  | Stephanie |

Categories

|id | category  | 
|---|-----------|
|0  | Technical |
|1  | General   |

Questions

|id | category_id | question                     | element            |
|---|-------------|---------------------------------------------------|
|0  | 0           | Which class you are in?      | textarea           |
|1  | 0           | Which languages do you know? | input[type="text"] |
|2  | 1           | Which area you are in?       | textarea           |
|3  | 1           | Which pllaces do you know?   | input[type="text"] |

Answers

|id | question_id | student_id | answer          |
|---|-------------|------------|-----------------|
|0  | 0           | 0          | Advanced MySql  |
|1  | 0           | 3          | Markdown 101    |
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , i did that. Now how can questions on the form page. I mean how should i iterate first through categories and then questions

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? You are trying to show your questions on a form page? Why do you need to pick and choose what to iterate? I would preform a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) which is something in MYSQL that merges two tables into one *temporarily*  table both categories and questions would be on in it.

Comment: Initially there will be no answer linked to user. but when i display the form then i need to bind the answer with answer entity